# Restful web service in Catalyst

Tags: json, web-services, perl, rest

Can anyone tell me how to send JSON request in Perl and how can I access JSON request object in catalyst?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

To start the process I'd look at this thread: [Perl JSON::RPC::Client using LWP::Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716904/perl-jsonrpcclient-using-lwpagent)

This gives two methods json rpc, I've used this in the past and a tailor-made method using LWP, I haven't tried anything like that.

Tell us how you do, best regards Hugh Barnard